# Using Akka and Protobufs in a client-server architecture

Tags: scala, tcp, client-server, akka, protocol-buffers

I want to be able to send Protobuf encoded messages from a client (written in C#.NET), to a remote Akka system (written in Scala). The Akka system will decode the message, process it, and return a Protobuf encoded response.

What is the simplest way to achieve this? Should I be using Akka IO TCP? http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/io-tcp.html

This looks appropriate, but the stuff around throttling and back pressure seems quite low-level and tricky.

It seems that if the client was written in Scala too, it could use Akka remoting to communicate with the remote Akka system. But since in my case the client is written in C#.NET, it is not clear what to do.

Does anyone have any experiences with building something similar?

Comment: The IO API is indeed very low level.  You'd be better suited looking at Akka Streams, which is built on top of the IO library and hides the intricacies of backpressure and some other low level concepts:  http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M5/scala.html?_ga=1.176262624.498900459.1411518540

Comment: We use Akka Streams to support a system where a C application is streaming protobuf content to an Akka Streams server and we've had great success with it.

Comment: This looks like a nice alternative. I will try it out, thanks!

Comment: @cmbaxter is this an alternative to using Akka actors? or can streams be used alongside an actor system? I already have an actor system that will process a request (i.e. a deserialized protobuf) message. I guess my question is: can I use streams just to handle the TCP connections/deserializing messages, or would I also need to rewrite my existing actor system to work with the streaming API?

Comment: You can definitely feed into an Actor instance as part of your stream handling.  You could start out by getting your protobuf deserialized first, using the stream stages (`map`, etc...), then use `mapAsync`/`mapAsyncUnordered` to perform an ask (`?`) to an actor instance and then re-convert that response back to protbuf in the streams code so it gets sent back out on the outgoing channel as bytes.

Comment: hmm ok... that sounds good. I'll try to do something like that :)

Comment: One other point, you will need to know how to properly frame your incoming protobuf data.  `ByteString`s will flow through the stream stages but they themselves do not know about the natural boundaries of your messages.  You should look at the streams cookbook section in the docs for ideas.  For us, because the channel stays open for the sending of many messages, we prefix our data with a 4 byte int representing the size of the actual payload then then aggregate until we hit that size before sending downstream to the next stage for deserialization.

Comment: Yeah I see, that makes sense. I was thinking I would have to somehow encode the byte size of each protobuf message, and that sounds like a good way to do it. It looks like there's quite a learning curve to using streams - I am just starting to go through the docs now. thanks again for the advice!